# Why doesn't pressing the Next button in iTunes Connect "Start External Testing" page do anything?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am submitting a build of my app to the Testflight Beta App Review, and hello human beings. And in the *Start External Testing* page, I've checked *Have you made any significant changes to this build since your previous submission?* to **No**. After I've filled out *What to Test*, *App Description*, and all the required fields (*Review Notes* doesn't need to be filled since the app doesn't need to be reviewed because I've checked the *significant changes* radio button to **No**). But when I press the *Next* button, a loader control appears next to the "Next" text, but after the loader control disappears, nothing happens, iTunes Connect didn't take me to the page about "encryption info", instead I stayed right there on the *Start External Testing* page! This is really frustrating, and I have a image over here to aid understanding.

[image]

Comment: I think it's a temporary problem on the server side, as I'm currently getting this too. But also, make sure all the required fields are filled out (e.g. What to Test, I think some of the URL and contact fields, and the Build Changes field).

Comment: fyi, I was able to get around the problem by opening a private browsing window in Safari. So doing that, or clearing cookies/cache might help.

Comment: @esker Your answer worked! Do you want to resubmit your response as an answer?

Comment: Same thing happening the last 3 days days to me. Private browsing doesn't resolve the issue. I will wait one more day... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my case was simply an Apple issue, as someone told above.

For me, the "clear/private browsing" was not a solution these days so I just wait. After 5 days, the "Next" button started to work as expected, followed by the "changes on encryption" page with a "Submit" button.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a server side issue at iTunes/Apple. I too had this problem and as some have commented clearing cookies or logging out/in seemed to do the trick, although not always.

Because you already have build out there that has been approved, there should be a submit button instead of a next button, as shown in the image below.

[image: How it is supposed to look]

All you can do at this point is try clearing cookies and try again (or boot up different browser), or submit another build and see if that works. Until Apple fixes this problem of course.